# What happens if fragmented IP datagram gets dropped (i.e. one fragment out of many)?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, mtu

I am a student just beginning to dive into the network stack, so please forgive any misconceptions.

If you are using TCP as a transport layer protocol, and sending payloads that happen to be greater than the MTU lower down in the stack, the Network Layer protocol (IPv4 for example) will fragment the payload into separate IP datagrams. What happens if a single one of these "fragmented" IP datagrams is dropped?

### Example

#### Sending 4000 byte datagram with MTU of 1500 bytes

1. *[MF: 1 Offset: 0 Length: 1500]*
2. *[MF: 1 Offset: 185 Length: 1500]* <--------- Dropped/Lost
3. *[MF: 0 Offset: 370 Length: 1040]*

#### Which would happen?

1. Only IP datagram #2 get re-transmitted
2. The entire 4000 byte datagram be fragmented again and entirely re-transmitted after TCP determines the datagram was lost

I was originally thinking that the individual fragment would be re-transmitted, however given that this is below the reliability ensured by TCP in the transport layer, I am now thinking that the entire TCP datagram is just dropped/re-transmitted (which seems inefficient).

As a follow up, is there any reason that this "fragmentation" occurs below the transport layer (specifically below TCP)? I feel like this could be handled most of the time by ensuring that packets are broken up into a generally acceptable MTU size above/at the transport layer. Upon some research I found some information on how TCP should have nothing to do with packetizing things, which I did not quite understand.

Comment: A single dropped fragment causes the packet to be dropped. Fragmentation is on the endangered species list as most businesses now drop packet fragments to prevent fragmentation attacks. IPv6 has eliminated in-path fragmentation, and we now have PMTUD to properly size packets prior to sending them.

Comment: By the way, your example is not realistic as the data must be fragmented at a point that is evenly divisible by eight.

Answer (score 0):

The entire 4000 byte datagram be fragmented again and entirely re-transmitted after TCP determines the datagram was lost.  Although TCP should break it up into MTU fit-able chunks (aka segments) in the first place.